# How to test a event in Jasmine node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, jasmine

I'm writing a node module that uses serial port communication.
All outgoing messages are called with write(), and all for all incoming messages, events are raised.

I would like to be able to test the incoming messages. When a write is called, it takes a very short time (less than a 1/10 second in good conditions) for the incoming message.

Snippet:

```
it("can receive", function() {
    btReader.on('dataReceived', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        expect(data).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

This way it will only make the event handler, but the complete test will be done before any event is raised. Then, when an event is raised, the code will execute, but it will not be really tested.

Will I have to use the waitsFor method, and then set a bool to true inside the eventhandler?

Comment: Have you looked at jasmine-node? It has nice async support: https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your event is asynchronous, yes, you will need to use the `waitsFor` method to test that the handler has been called. You are exactly right that you will need to create a variable to test. So what you end up with are 3 parts to the [test](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/#section-Asynchronous_Support):

1. The initial setup and event call (i.e. `write` and some variable set to false).
2. The `waitsFor` method where the variable is set to true.
3. The final expectation test that makes sure the variable has been set to true.

The `waitsFor` method expects a timeout parameter, so if it takes 200ms to run your function, then give the timeout a reasonable value to make sure it never fails unexpectedly. Of course, you don't have to do a simple test like the one above, you could set the variable to whatever the write method does and make sure that it has done what it was supposed to do.

Comment: It feels a bit like a workaround to me, but I see it's probably the only way to do so with Jasmine. Thanks!

Comment: How do you mean it's a workaround? Javascript executes synchronously and this callback method is a pretty standard pattern across all unit test frameworks. QUnit has a `stop()` and `start()` method which is a bit unintuitive. I think Jasmine is the most intuitive for asynchronous testing (personal opinion though).

Comment: Maybe the definition 'workaround' is a bit too harsh. I was just wondering if it's possible to do without extra variable. (Not used to testing frameworks, and I really like Jasmine at the moment.)

Comment: It depends if there's anything to test. If you're just testing that the event was raised, then that's the best way really. It looks like it returns data however, so you could test the data instead (you would still need to define it out of scope, but you would actually be testing something that way).